# How can i use intent on Listview while im using searchbox

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-intent

I have a problem with my code and still confused about intent which each item have their own layout like a product with their own description
Anybody know how to solve my problem? thank you before

and this is my main_activity code

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static com.example.vinznolimit.herbindonesia.R.id.theList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private ArrayAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView list= (ListView) findViewById(theList);
        EditText theFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchFilter);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Started.");

        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        names.add("Mitch");
        names.add("Blake");
        names.add("Blade");
        names.add("Bruno");
        names.add("Joe");
        names.add("Barry");

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.list_item,names);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);



theFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                (MainActivity.this).adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });



    }
}
```

Comment: you can use listview.setOnItemClickListener(); in this method you can use the intent

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
        int position, long id) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), UserSubmissionLog.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);

        }
    }
);
```